# lvalue grammar in yacc reduces incorrectly

Tags: c, grammar, yacc

I'm trying to parse multidimensional arrays with YACC. Here is my lvalue definition:

```
    lvalue: ID { EM_debug("got lvalue identifier " + to_String($1));
            $$.My_VAR = A_SimpleVar($$.pos, $1);
            $$.size = 0;
            $$.name = $1;
        }
    | lvalue L_SQUARE_BRACKET exp R_SQUARE_BRACKET { EM_debug("got lvalue[exp]");
            $$.My_VAR = A_SubscriptVar($$.pos, $1.My_VAR, $3.My_AST);
            $$.size = $3.My_AST;
            $$.name = $1.name;
        }
    ;
```

For the (simplified) input `ia[2]` it prints `got lvalue identifier ia` and gives a parsing error when it encounters the left bracket. I don't get why this would not work. It should see the left bracket in its lookahead and shift. It should not reduce immediately like this. How can I prevent it from shifting?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use YACC for lval vs. rval distinguishing.  Because an lval is also almost always an rval, it creates reduce/reduce conflicts in the grammar and that makes it non-deterministic.

Use a Semantic Analysis phase to check for lval correctness rather than incorporating it into the YACC grammar.

For reference though, GNU Bison handles reduce/reduce conflicts by reducing by the rule which is defined first in the file.  So that might help you temporarily get around your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Bison isn't telling me there is a reduce/reduce conflict. And I did try swapping the order and nothing changed.

Comment: @phileaton Hmmm, in that case I can't help you.  The example code you gave is cryptic at best and there isn't enough context for me to find out what went wrong.  Run `bison` with the `--verbose --debug` options and post all of the output from compiling and from running the program.  `--verbose` puts its output in a file ending a `.out` extension while `--debug` puts it on stderr when the program runs.

Comment: Perhaps this is not the best place to post that output. There are 120~ states and the output was much too large to be allowed in my post.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, the reduction is completely correct. In order to apply

```
lvalue: lvalue L_SQUARE_BRACKET exp R_SQUARE_BRACKET
```

to the input

```
ia[2]
```

the parser needs to make `ia` into an `lvalue` before shifting the <kbd>[</kbd> (assuming that `L_SQUARE_BRACKET` is a <kbd>[</kbd>, see below). It does this by using the rule `lvalue: ID`, so we can expect that rule to run before the <kbd>[</kbd> is shifted.

So that's not the problem, and there's not enough information in the question to provide a better diagnosis. However, for what it's worth, a few notes:

1) Personally, I find it much less error-prone and easier to read to use literal characters in bison rules:

```
lvalue: lvalue '[' exp ']'
```

which of course needs to be matched with a flex rule which returns the literal characters:

```
"["|"]"  { return *yytext; }
```

(or, using the possibly less readable syntax: `[][]` which can be extended to a longer list of single character tokens, such as `[][(){}<>=+*/-]`: just remember that `]` must come first and `-` last in a character class).

It's entirely possible that there is a mismatch between your scanner and your parser which results in the `[` not being sent with the correct token type; you certainly need to eliminate that possibility for debugging.

2) Is bison telling you about any conflicts (including shift-reduce conflicts)? Each of these needs to be tracked down and eliminated.

3) How do you know that the syntax error is being generated when the `[` is seen? Have you, for example, enabled flex debugging traces (very handy for debugging) and/or bison debugging traces (which I find more useful than scattering print statements in your actions, but YMMV)?

Comment: The answer was exactly that I was not scanning the left bracket. Good call on the correctness! Thanks!